# Building Custom Kali Linux ISO Image Failed

Tags: kali-linux, mkfs, live-build

I'm using a Kali Linux on virtual box and I'm currently trying to create a custom Kali Linux ISO using the following commands:

```
apt-get install git live-build cdebootstrap
git clone https://gitlab.com/kalilinux/build-scripts/live-build-config.git
cd live-build-config/
./build.sh --distribution kali-rolling --verbose
```

Everything works fine and the process takes around 30 mins until it fails to create the Image. Checking the build.log file I find the last lines saying the following:

```
mkfs.fat 4.2 (2021-01-31)
Volume ID does not fit in 32 bit
E: An unexpected failure occurred , exiting ...
P: Begin unmounting filesystems ...
P: Saving caches ...
Reading package lists ...
Building dependency tree ...
Reading state information ...
```

Screenshot attached below.

[image]

Comment: If you want to ask here instead, please delete the duplicate on [su]. Or keep that one and delete this, the question is on topic on both sites. That said, did you try setting a smaller volume name? The error seems quite clear: `Volume ID does not fit in 32 bit`. I also see in the log that `mkfs.msdos` is printing its usage message, which suggests it was called with wrong parameters. You need to check the source of whatever script you are running and see what it is executing for `mkfs.msdos`.

Comment: Well thanks for your quick response. I've deleted the duplication on Super User.
Regarding the script I've checked it and can't seem to find anything related to `mkfs.mdos` I'm kinda new to this and using the `build.sh` provided on Kali website on this link [https://gitlab.com/kalilinux/build-scripts/live-build-config/](https://gitlab.com/kalilinux/build-scripts/live-build-config/)